# Is the T in Jo Reggelt silent, or not?

Tags: pronunciation, hungarian

Some local (american) men of Hungarian descent greet each other in the morning  **Jo Reggel**.
When I searched online, it always turned up as **Jo Reggel*t***, and the **T** is pronounced. When I asked them about it, they claimed it is a mistake, as they grew up hearing **Jo Reggel**, without the **T**.

Am I missing something, or maybe they are wrong after all?

Comment: How do they say ‘good day’? _Jó nap_? Or _jó napot_?

Comment: How do they say 'happy birthday'? *Boldog születésnap*? Or *boldog születésnapot*? How about 'good luck' which is *sokszerencsét* in the Hungarian I know but I guess would be *sokszerencse* for the men you know.

Answer (score 3):

Just like in neighbouring languages like German and Czech, greetings in Hungarian usually are in the accusative case. Therefore, it's *Jó reggelt*. The *t* is present and pronounced. I guess it's short for *Jó reggelt kívánok* or some such construction (that means "I wish [you] a good morning")

But many European languages that are also spoken in America have some differences from where they're spoken natively. That is, some New World language varieties have diverged grammaticaly from the way they are spoken in Europe. I can easily imagine that this is one of those cases, and that the men you know simply have a different grammar from what's common in Hungary and surrounding areas.

Comment: *Jó reggel* as a greeting is plainly wrong. As a native speaker, I find it exceedingly unlikely that such a form could exist in any *living* New World variety. It is much more likely that these speakers never learned the language well, and do not use it actively (except maybe the greeting).